# Echo tinyint in wordpress admin page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

hope someone can help me with this little problem.
I am trying to echo a tinyint from my MySQL in my backend page to see who accepted and who did not.

this is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $wpdb;

$result2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ReparationQuotes ORDER BY Id DESC", OBJECT);
?>

<?php foreach ($result2 as $q2) {
    //$quote2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Accepted FROM ReparationQuotes Where ReparationId = '" . esc_sql($q2->Id) . "'", OBJECT);
    if ($q2->Accepted == 1)
    $accepted = "true";
    elseif ($q2->Accepted == 0)
    $accepted = "false";
}
    ?>
```

Then I am trying to call the variable in my table

```
<td class="post-title page-title column title">
        <strong> <?php echo $accepted ?> </strong>
    </td>
```

Unluckily this is only placing "false". No where to find True.
It seems like it is getting the values wrong from mysql.

If I change 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 everything is "true".
What might be the problem here?
Thanks all for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I edited my php which brings out the 0 and 1 where seemed necessary.
The tinyint cels which have not been filled in will echo "Geen offerte".

This is my result:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM Reparation ORDER BY Id DESC", OBJECT);
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ReparationQuotes ORDER BY ReparationId DESC", OBJECT);
?>

<?php
if(count($result) > 0) {

    foreach($result as $rep) {

        $quote = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(Id) as total FROM ReparationQuotes WHERE ReparationId = '" . esc_sql($rep->Id) . "'", OBJECT);

        foreach ($result2 as $q2) {
        $quote2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Accepted FROM ReparationQuotes Where ReparationId = '" . esc_sql($rep->Id) ."'", OBJECT);
    }
        ?>
```

and then to output the file like this:

```
<td class="post-title page-title column title">
            <strong><?php if ($quote2) : ?> 
            <?php echo $quote2[0]->Accepted; ?>                     
            <?php else: ?> 
    <p style="background-color: gray;">Geen offerte</p> 
<?php endif; ?>  </strong>
        </td>
```

I opened another question for edits in this code, because not everything seemed to work the way I want it to, but atleast this does the trick until then.